# What are screw drive lenses?

Tags: lens, terminology, lens-design, old-lenses

Are lenses known as screw drivers actually available?
If so what are their features and why are they called so.
Name some of the lens and their manufactures.

Comment: For completeness' sake, a screwdriver drink is vodka and orange juice.

Comment: Note that most older lenses are "screw drive" and need an in body AF drive motor. If you buy a camera body with this capability you can use most older lenses. If you don't you will not be able to use AF. Older lenses can provide excellent bargains for the very keen - so an in body motor camera can be valuable to have. Also - eg Nikon  AF-S lenses with the in-lens motor trend to be substantially more costly than the equivalent lens with no in lens motor. eg I just bought a Nikon 50mm f/1.8 AF for about $NZ180. The AF-S equivalent with in lens motor is close To $NZ400.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's "screw drive", and it's the type of lens driven by an autofocus motor in the camera body. The link between the body and the lens is very like that between a screwdriver and a screw. Most of the older AF Nikkors, Minolta As/Sony αs and Pentax AF lenses use that drive system. Newer lenses tend to have their own autofocus motors and are driven by the body electrically rather than mechanically. The Canon EF mount has always had in-lens focus motors.